# Combining 'using' and 'reinterpret_cast'

Tags: c++11

I have a list of functions that are put in a table for lookup for an interpreter. I cast each function to void (*) () as follows:

```
using vptr = void (*) (); // cast to a function that takes no args, and returns no result

struct function date_funs[] =
{
  {C_FN3, X_A3, "III", (vptr) do_hms_to_time, "hms_to_time"}, 
  ...
```

This works, and does exactly what I want. I wonder if there was another way of expressing it, like:

```
using vptr = reinterpret_cast<void(*) ()>;
```

The C++ compiler complains of a syntax error, though. Is there any way I can fix this, or should I just use the first form of `vptr` that I devised?

Comment: Do your functions have different signature than `void()`?

Comment: @Akira: yes, they have a different signature to `void()` ... otherwise there'd be no need to recast.

Comment: In that case if you know the arguments being passed, it is safe to use `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

`using` (in this context) defines a type alias. In your attempt, you are not giving a type, but have a partial expression, which is a syntax error.

To shorten usages, e.g. `reinterpret_cast<void(*) ()>(do_hms_to_time)`, you could introduce a function as well as the using.

```
using vptr = void (*) ();
template <typename Func>
constexpr vptr to_vptr(Func && func)
{ return reinterpret_cast<vptr>(func); }
```

and use it

```
  {C_FN3, X_A3, "III", to_vptr(do_hms_to_time), "hms_to_time"},
```

Comment: What would happen if I use this function on a function with signature e.g. `double(int, int)` then invoke the resulting pointer?

Comment: @Akira undefined behaviour